# comparing present time to created time and deleting from parse via javascript

Tags: parse-platform, utc

I am trying to find all the photoInfo posts that have current date greater than the present date in UTC and then delete them from the Parse server.The code has no errors and prints out success.However, it does not delete the posts.Help please.createdAt is in UTC format on the Parse server hence i convert my present date to UTC format as well for the comparison

```
Parse.Cloud.job('deleteThirtyMinsPics', function(request, status) {


            // All access

            Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();





            var today = new Date();

            var days = 1;

            var time = (30 * 3600 * 1000);



            var d = new Date();
            var m = new Date(today.getTime() + (time));
            var time = d.toUTCString();


            var PhotoInfo = Parse.Object.extend("PhotoInfo");
            var photoInfo = new PhotoInfo()
            var photoInfoQuery = new Parse.Query("PhotoInfo");
            var createdAt = photoInfo.createdAt;


            photoInfoQuery.greaterThan(createdAt,time);


            photoInfoQuery.find().then(function (posts) {

                                       Parse.Object.destroyAll(posts, {

                                                               success: function() {

                                                               status.success('Success');

                                                               },

                                                               error: function(error) {

                                                               status.error('Error, posts are not removed.');

                                                               }

                                                               });

                                       }, function (error) {});




            });
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly.. Do you want to delete last 30 min data??
whats the use of "m". You did not use it anywhere.

Comment: Your query wont be succesful, because you are querying for objects whose time of creation is greater than present time. So no objects will be returned

Comment: so i want to delete the posts after a period of time but i wrote this code to test to see if the post will be deleted after the function was called.I changed the greaterthan to less than in photoInfoQuery.greaterThan(createdAt,time); Which from my understanding deletes all the posts that have present date greater than the created date but the posts are still not being deleted

Comment: photoInfoQuery.greaterThan(createdAt,time); change this to 
photoInfoQuery.lessThan("createdAt",time);

Comment: i tried that too and it did not work .Even with single quotes.I've been playing around with the code for over a week and can't seem to figure out the problem